# What brand of doorbell chime is this?

Tags: doorbell

My doorbell doesn't work, and because of the previous owner stuccoing over it, I had to damage it to the point of looking not very good anymore to remove it. Turns out it's battery powered, as is my doorbell chime.

To make sure I get the right doorbell branch to match my chime, could someone tell me what brand of chime this is, if it's possible to tell?

[image]

Comment: Unless it is just a few years old, good chance a new one might not work.  Is there no name/label inside the cover?  Would need same make and more important the model number, different model number probably won't work.

Comment: I haven't seen anything as far as labeling, but I'll take a closer look in it. The batteries inside of it *expired* in 2014, so it's definitely more than just a few years old.

Comment: Will probably be easier just to replace with a new system.  Matching of the codes is usually hard unless both pieces are matched, same model and possible same year(like tv remotes, can't see different buttons activating different bells).